# In Erlang is there a tool to generate all the message passing among processes?

Tags: erlang

It would be very helpful to see that process A(gen_server) use  gen_cast to send message to process B(gen_server), process B use gen_cast or some other way to inform process A or even go through process C to do it.

Is there a tool to generate this kind of sequence diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [tool called ET](http://erlang.org/doc/man/et.html) (part of OTP). It's usage is described in [blog post by Jesper Louis](http://jlouisramblings.blogspot.dk/2011/10/using-event-tracer-tool-set-in-erlang.html).

Comment: Thanks, it looks great.